# JSpinner with Display Format, Numbers only and manual edit

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

It is required to create a **JSpinner** with following features.

- Range should be 0 to 1000 with 10 increment.
- Display format should be 4 digits. (ex : 10 -> 0010)
- It must allow user to enter the values manually.
- It should not allow characters other than digits.
- It should not allow enter values having more than 3 digits.

This is my current implementation :

```
spinnerUpDown.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(0,0,1000,10));
spinnerUpDown.setEditor(new JSpinner.NumberEditor(spinnerUpDown,"0000"));
JFormattedTextField txt = ((JSpinner.NumberEditor) spinnerUpDown.getEditor()).getTextField();
((NumberFormatter) txt.getFormatter()).setAllowsInvalid(false);
```

Problem with that implementation is, it will not allow user to manually enter a value.

If I remove the line :

```
((NumberFormatter) txt.getFormatter()).setAllowsInvalid(false);
```

It will allow me to enter values manually, but it allows to enter letters also.

Any suggestions to over come this problem. 
Thank you!!

Comment: +1 1.) don't know, really there must be input mask and mask formatter and some verifier, don't know how to do it, 2.) `Problem with that implementation is, it will not allow user to manually enter a value.` will be solved by DocumentFilter with pattern (many times aked here, btw I'posted here a few times JSpinner & DocumentFilter)

Comment: I find your description of the allowable values to be confusing.  Can you show some 'sample values' that comply with all rules?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson It should allow all the values in between 0 and 1000. Problem with the current implementation is, when user select all current value and enter a new value it will accept only the first digit. Ex: if the current value is 25 then it will display as 0025. after user select all 4digits and try to enter 10, it will display 0001 and lost the selection.

Comment: you can to override something as setEchoChar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JSpinner` typically uses a `JTextComponent` for its editor. You could get the editor and apply a [`DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) to it.

This will allow you to filter the text coming into the document.

Check these, often cited, [examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter)

**Example**

`JFormattedTextField` is installing it's own `DocumentFilter`.  You can overcome this by providing your own `PlainDocument` that returns it's own filter

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;
import javax.swing.text.PlainDocument;

public class TestSpinner01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestSpinner01();
    }

    public TestSpinner01() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JSpinner spinnerUpDown = new JSpinner();
                spinnerUpDown.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 1000, 10));
                spinnerUpDown.setEditor(new JSpinner.NumberEditor(spinnerUpDown, "0000"));
                System.out.println(spinnerUpDown.getEditor());


                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                frame.add(spinnerUpDown);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                PlainDocument doc = new PlainDocument() {
                    private TestFilter filter;
                    @Override
                    public DocumentFilter getDocumentFilter() {
                        if (filter == null) {
                            filter = new TestFilter();
                        }
                        return filter;
                    }

                };

                JTextComponent txt = ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor) spinnerUpDown.getEditor()).getTextField();
                txt.setDocument(doc);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestFilter extends DocumentFilter {

        @Override
        public void remove(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length) throws BadLocationException {
            System.out.println("remove");
            super.remove(fb, offset, length);
        }

        @Override
        public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
            System.out.println("insert");
            super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
        }

        @Override
        public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
            System.out.println("Replace...");
            super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
        }
    }
}
```

Strangely enough, you example code worked well for me, but the problem I actually had was to do with the formatter

Comment: I just try to add a DocumentFilter: `JFormattedTextField txt = ((JSpinner.NumberEditor) spinnerUpDown.getEditor()).getTextField();((AbstractDocument) txt.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new NumericAndLengthFilter(4))` But is seems that filter is never used. I try the same document filter with JTextField and it works fine.

Comment: Thank you for the code sample. It works perfectly. Only different is I am setting DocumentFilter directly and your set the Document with a Filter. I have know idea why it behave like that. Any way thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Register `KeyListener` for `JFormattedTextField`. In the `keyPressed()` method, if the typed key is non-numeric character, then you can set the character of `KeyEvent` to empty string. so nothing will be appearing in the `JFormattedTextField`

Comment: You should never us a KeyListener to try and filter a text component